# Google Voice Search: Multiple languages in desktop search?

Tags: google-search

The Google application on my iOS device allows me to search both in English and in foreign languages, at the same time. In other words, I just start speaking, and it will recognize the language.

It seems that Google Voice Search with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) via a desktop web browser (like Chrome on OS X), does not in the default setting allow multiple languages at the same time.

Is there a language setting somewhere, where I can add my language to the list of languages to parse when voice searching?

---

NB: Interestingly, the mobile Google app is the only Google application that I have found that can take multiple language inputs. The mobile Chrome app on iOS, does not.